# Update entire document in mongodb using morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have document which I need to update but updated parameters are not same all the time it depends on user. So how can I update document or replace whole document with new values based on id.

Answer (score 0):

You wrap your updated values in a `Map` the set the update:

```
Map<String, Object> updateInfo; // Key is db column name, value is updatedValue

Then create update operations:

Query<Entity> filter = datastore.createQuery(Entity.class)
                                .field("_id", id);

UpdateOperations<Entity> updateOps = datastore.createUpdateOperations(Entity.class);

updateInfo.entrySet().forEach(e -> updateOps.set(e.getKey(), e.getValue());

datastore.update(filter, updateOps);
```

By this way, you can update entity with any number of fields

Comment: At runtime I am unaware of which values has been changed so anyways I have to set all the columns and it's values in map. My class is too big so it's not feasible to set all the values through map.put("key","value") statement.

Comment: Compare input and existing object, you'll know which value is changed.